# Scala Play: Retrieve a dynamic substring from between two known strings

Tags: regex, scala, cookies, playframework

Total Scala neophyte here.

I'm trying to get a handle on Play, and how we can utilize it in our environment.  Part of the requirements for the app we need to build is that we hit an external web api, which kicks back an authorization id in the header of the login request.

I'm using the WS library to execute the `POST` call to the login service, and can get the headers with `val cookie = response.header("Set-Cookie").toString`

That returns a string that looks like this:

`Some(JSESSIONID=1234XYZ5678ABC; Path=/some_path/; HttpOnly)`

What do I need to do to retrieve the `1234XYZ5678ABC` in the above string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex).
2. Use this RegExp: `(?<=JSESSIONID=)[A-Z0-9]+(?=;)`.

Comment: Seems like the right start, but it's not returning things exactly correctly.  Doing `"(?<=JSESSIONID=)[A-Z0-9]+(?=;)".r.findFirstIn("Some(JSESSIONID=1234XYZ5678ABC; Path=/some_path/; HttpOnly)"` returns `Option[String] = Some(1234XYZ5678ABC)`, instead of just `Option[String] = 1234XYZ5678ABC`.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Grad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Play provides any convenience methods, but here is general Scala way of doing it:

```
scala> val sessionIdRegex = """^.*JSESSIONID=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$""".r
sessionIdRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^.*JSESSIONID=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$

scala> val rawSessionData = Some("JSESSIONID=1234XYZ5678ABC; Path=/some_path/; HttpOnly") 
rawSessionData: Some[String] = Some(JSESSIONID=1234XYZ5678ABC; Path=/some_path/; HttpOnly)

scala> for {
     | sessionInfo <- rawSessionData
     | sessionIdRegex(sessionId) <- sessionIdRegex findFirstIn sessionInfo
     | } yield sessionId
res0: Option[String] = Some(1234XYZ5678ABC)
```

You can use `getOrElse(<default>)` on result *if* you have to extract some value from that option. Adjust regex accordingly for more strict requirements or for extracting multiple groups/variables.